# Do these sentences have the same meaning: "Such a pity your father can't be here." VS "I wish your father was here."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

**"Such a pity your father can't be here."** [A Dark Adapted Eye (1994 UK TV drama, part 1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sE1hYGKNXt0&list=PLg187HkgVSMd7ddkbI6VyeK39kUmWpJ-i) (see:1:07:18-1:07:22)

**"I wish your father was here."**

These sentences, despite having completely different structures, seem to have the same meaning, at least when I translate it in mind. So, I have a tendency to accept **"Such a pity....."** and **"I wish ....."** as equivalents.

However, I am not quite sure if they are really equivalents in the minds of native speakers.

So, do these sentences produce the same meaning in your mind, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously they both express a similar idea, but they don't literally 'mean the same'.

*I wish your father was here* is a statement of the speaker's personal feelings.

*[It's] such a pity that your father can't be here* implies that the father's absence is regrettable for everyone (or for all the family members present).